# Objective C - RegEx - Invalid Range when trying to match spaces

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to validate a FULL NAME , i.e  "John Smith" and allow spaces ( 1 or more)

I'm using the following code:
My regex pattern looks like this?

```
[A-Za-z_.- ]{2,39}";
```

I have seen in previous posts to add a space to match on space. I have also tried prefixing the space with back slashes. I added a 'space' after the '-'.

When I run my code

```
NSString *FilterString = @"[A-Za-z_.- ]{2,39}";
NSString *nameRegex = FilterString;
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
return [nameTest evaluateWithObject:self];
```

I get the following error:

**Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE (string John Smith, pattern [A-Za-z_.- ]{2,39}, case 0, canon 0)**

What is the correct pattern to match spaces? What is wrong with the above?

Comment: `.- ` is an invalid range of characters.

Comment: duplicate is hyphens.. where is the questions about spaces?

Comment: The issue is the hyphen, not the space. **You're creating a range**